# How to sort a list obtained in a dictionary by a specific value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a bit of code set up that grabs the .JSON file from all players that have one to their name, open that and pull out values, and place it all in a list to attach to a dictionary. The idea is to take that information, and to apply it in descending order and print it out. Rather than trying to show the .JSON files and all, I did my best to create an example script and run it to test around with. It is the following:

```py
dictExample = {1:["Sam", "Player 1", 1, 3], 2:["Sue", "Player 2", 4 ,3],3:["Goerge", "Player 3", 3, 3],4:["Jorge", "Player 4", 0, 0]}

sorted()
num = input("number: ")

for num in range(1, 5):
    total = dictExample[num][2] + dictExample[num][3]
    try:
        percent = (dictExample[num][2] / total) * 100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        percent = 0
    print(dictExample[num][1] + " (" + dictExample[num][0] + "): " + str(dictExample[num][2]) + "wins/" + str(dictExample[num][3]) + "losses. (" + strExample(percent) + "%)")
```

I would like it to arrange the dictionary in the following way: `{1:["Sue", "Player 2", 4 ,3], 2:["Goerge", "Player 3", 3, 3], 3:["Sam", "Player 1", 1, 3], 1:["Jorge", "Player 4", 0, 0]}` This way the dictionary can be ran through that for statement, and list them in descending order according to the value found in the second index.

I have tried looking around on the internet for options to help me with, but every example I find is always a 1 to 1 ratio. Meaning one key always has only one value Most common example is: `{4:Four, 2:Two, 3:Three, 1:One}`, and how to use the sort(), or sorted() functions to order them how you want.

Do I need to run a loop to place it all into one giant list inside a single list? Or is there a way to manipulate the data as is? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what results do you expect from thedata given above?

Comment: I will edit, but I would like it to arrange the dictionary in the following way:

{1:["Sue", "Player 2", 4 ,3], 2:["Goerge", "Player 3", 3, 3], 3:["Sam", "Player 1", 1, 3], 1:["Jorge", "Player 4", 0, 0]}

This way the above dictionary can be ran through that for statement, and list them in descending order according to the value found in the second index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ??

```py
>>> indices = sorted(dictExample, key=lambda d: dictExample[d][2], reverse=True)
>>> for i in indices:
        print(dictExample[i])

['Sue', 'Player 2', 4, 3]
['Goerge', 'Player 3', 3, 3]
['Sam', 'Player 1', 1, 3]
['Jorge', 'Player 4', 0, 0]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I got something similar, but could only do it using multiple functions. I suspected it could be done with a lambda expression, but kept failing, but I think I can piece together how and why this works with your example. Thanks.